# Don't you do this vs Don't do this

Tags: connotation, repetition, imperatives

Could anyone clarify, please, what the difference between these two sentences is? 
I heard an American woman say to her child: "Don't you do this!"

Comment: "Don't you do ..." is what you say to a child.  The word "dare" is elided but implied.

Comment: Normally the _you_ is not said, but if it is, it's a mark of emphasis, as to a child, where it usually means -- or is intended to be interpreted as -- "I'm getting angry". Adding _dare_, as @HotLicks points out, is another emphatic marker.

Comment: And heaven help you if your mother says your full name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Lawler has explained, **"don't you do that"** adds emphasis to **"don't do that"**.

That's what a mother would say to a child, a teacher to a naughty pupil, a wife to a reckless husband and, as Hot Licks points out, "dare" is implied most of the time.

> "William James, don't you do that! Put the cat down immediately."

Whether "don't you do that" sounds more or less bossy, largely depends on the **intonation** one uses. It can be a friendly and loving **"don't you do that...no....please...not here"** or a real order **"DON'T YOU DO THAT !!!"**

Answer (score 1):

An imperative sentence has the implied subject "you;" therefore you can say, "Don't do this."